# How to keep this in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var pageInit = (function(){
    var regBtn = function(){
        var ls = document.querySelectorAll("li");
        for (var i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {
            ls[i].onclick = menuClick;  
        }
    };
    var menuClick = function(){
        console.log(ls[i]);
    };
    return {
        regBtn: regBtn
    };
})();

window.onload = function(){
    pageInit.regBtn();
};
```

I'm starting modulation of coding javascript now.
But faced with the problem of function scope.
I know what the problem is but don't know how to solve it.
menuClick can't read the ls[i].
I tried **ls[i].onclick = this.menuClick;** or **menuClick.bind(this)** but useless.
How to solve problems like this?
I know how closure is but dont know how to solve this through bind() call() etc.

Comment: try to move menuClick function iside regBtn function

Comment: change `var menuClick = function(){
        console.log(this);
    };`

Comment: note: `this` inside menuClick will be the element that was clicked - so you don't even need to worry about "closure inside for loops"

Comment: Oh I see .Thx a lot !